# Prevent Other Month Events From Rendering in jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'd like to prohibit fullcalendar from displaying events in the other month cells. I figured I could do this with the eventRender event.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: $.fullCalendar.myFeed(),
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        if (event.start.getMonth() != ????)
            $(element).hide();
   }
});
```

I can't figure out what to replace the ???? to get the calendar's current month. Anybody have some tips?

Answer (score 3):

I guess there isn't a way to reference the parent calendar from within this event. "this" refers to the event object. I didn't realize that the view also gets passed as a third parameter. I was able to accomplish this using the following code:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: $.fullCalendar.myFeed(),
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            if (event.start.getMonth() != view.start.getMonth())
                return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's a good solution. But is there a way to not even render those dates in the calendar?

Comment: I also needed solution for this. Please share some links if someone has any solution for the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a fullcalendar with year view (https://github.com/tpruvot/fullcalendar).
You cannot use view.start.getMonth() on year view.
I used a little trick passing through eventAfterRender :

```
eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
    var col=element.closest('td').index()+1;
    var $cellh=element.closest('table').find('thead td:nth-child('+col+')');
    if ($cellh.hasClass('fc-other-month') == true)
            element.css('visibility','hidden')
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some custom style

```css
.fc-other-month {
    background: white !important;
}

.fc-row .fc-bg {
    z-index: 5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The solution here: using day of `fc-other-month` over the day of `curent-month` with background white.

Answer (score 0):

```html
eventRender: function(event, element) {

  var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
  if (event.start.month() == view.intervalStart.month()) {
    element.addClass("bg-blue");
  }
},
```